# Apache mod_rewrite encode query string parameters

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I have a URL coming into apache 2.4:

`http://localhost/index.html?q=asdf&b=a|c|e&c=4&d=dsjklkjhd`

I need mod_rewrite to URLencode the `|` so that I get:

`http://localhost/index.html?q=asdf&b=a%7Cc%7Ce&c=4&d=dsjklkjh`

I cannot figure out how to do it, looked here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938598/rewrite-to-append-to-query-string#15938642

Here

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

I'm stumped, tried all kinds of stuff.  How to do this?

*Edit*

If I try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \|
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ /processing/%{QUERY_STRING} [QSD]
RewriteRule ^processing/(.+) /index.html?$1 [R=302,L]
```

I get this in the logs:

access.log

> "-" 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Mar/2019:08:37:00 -0400] "GET /index.html?q=asdf&b=a|c|e&c=4&d=dsjklkjhd HTTP/1.1" 200 520

error.log

> [Sat Mar 16 08:37:00.723831 2019] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 13] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 172.17.0.1:45194] 172.17.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#558a781fd350][rid#558a782e2e90/initial] applying pattern '.*' to uri '/index.html'
>
> [Sat Mar 16 08:37:00.723838 2019] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 13] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 172.17.0.1:45194] 172.17.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#558a781fd350][rid#558a782e2e90/initial] RewriteCond: input='GET' pattern='^TRACE' => not-matched
>
> [Sat Mar 16 08:37:00.723843 2019] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 13] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 172.17.0.1:45194] 172.17.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#558a781fd350][rid#558a782e2e90/initial] RewriteCond: input='GET' pattern='^OPTIONS' => not-matched
>
> [Sat Mar 16 08:37:00.723847 2019] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 13] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 172.17.0.1:45194] 172.17.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#558a781fd350][rid#558a782e2e90/initial] RewriteCond: input='GET' pattern='^DELETE' => not-matched
>
> [Sat Mar 16 08:37:00.723852 2019] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 13] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 172.17.0.1:45194] 172.17.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#558a781fd350][rid#558a782e2e90/initial] RewriteCond: input='GET' pattern='^PUT' => not-matched
>
> [Sat Mar 16 08:37:00.723855 2019] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 13] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 172.17.0.1:45194] 172.17.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#558a781fd350][rid#558a782e2e90/initial] applying pattern '^index\.html$' to uri '/index.html'
>
> [Sat Mar 16 08:37:00.723867 2019] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 13] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 172.17.0.1:45194] 172.17.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#558a781fd350][rid#558a782e2e90/initial] applying pattern '^processing/(.+)' to uri '/index.html'
>
> [Sat Mar 16 08:37:00.723874 2019] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 13] mod_rewrite.c(470): [client 172.17.0.1:45194] 172.17.0.1 - - [localhost/sid#558a781fd350][rid#558a782e2e90/initial] pass through /index.html
>
> [Sat Mar 16 08:37:00.724892 2019] [authz_core:debug] [pid 13] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 172.17.0.1:45194] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
>
> [Sat Mar 16 08:37:00.724914 2019] [authz_core:debug] [pid 13] mod_authz_core.c(809): [client 172.17.0.1:45194] AH01626: authorization result of : granted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache only appears to re-encode the *substitution* string if it changes in some way. So, one way to do this (to URL encode the pipe symbol `|` in the requested query string) is to *temporarily* rewrite the request (internally) to something entirely different and then *redirect* it back again. The redirect then URL encodes the complete *substitution* string (avoiding a redirect/rewrite loop):

For example (**UPDATED** for a server/vHost context):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \|
RewriteRule ^/index\.html$ /processing/%{QUERY_STRING} [QSD]
RewriteRule ^/processing/(.+) /index.html?$1 [R=302,L]
```

The first rule internally rewrites the request (that contains a `|` symbol in the query string) to `/processing/` and passes the `QUERY_STRING` as pathname information. The query string is discarded.

The very next rule immediately *redirects* it back to the required URL, but this time it should be re-encoded, URL encoding `|` as `%7c` in the query string.

Note that this triggers a 302 (temporary) redirect. Only change it to a 301 (permanent) redirect - if that is the intention - once you have confirmed that it works as intended, to avoid caching issues.

Comment: See my edit above - the issue is the same I've been having, that is, it does not seem to pickup the query string regex.  I do not see that it's finding the `|` in the query string

Comment: Ah, I've assumed these directives are in a _directory_ (or `.htaccess`) context - from your logs it looks like these are in a server/vHost context. You'll need slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ (otherwise they simply won't match - which is what your log is showing - the condition that checks for `|` is not even being processed). I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah, I had sorted that and your answer is the working one - thanks